# changing color of a textview by argument from color column in database. android

Tags: android, database, colors, cursor

Im displaying one column from my database with names of an events in a ListView by SimpleCursorAdapter, one of my column from database contains String names of a colors, is it possible to display this entries from database in different colors depending on their value from this color column?

```
 String[] from = new String[] { "event" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.eventTextView };
    conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Clock.this, R.layout.day_plan, null, from, to);
    setListAdapter(conAdapter);
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to use a custom adapter.

Comment: do You know any tutorials with that ?